# unfamiliar codes in iw

Tags: c

Recently I am trying to understand how the codes in iw works. In iw.h, I encountered the following:

```
#define __COMMAND(sect, name, args, nlcmd, flags, idby, handler)    \
static const struct cmd __cmd_ ## handler ## nlcmd ## idby  \
__attribute__((used)) __attribute__((section("__cmd")))     \
= { sect, name, args, nlcmd, flags, idby, handler }
#define COMMAND(section, name, args, cmd, flags, idby, handler) \
__COMMAND(#section, #name, args, cmd, flags, idby, handler)
#define TOPLEVEL(name, args, cmd, flags, idby, handler)     \
__COMMAND(NULL, #name, args, cmd, flags, idby, handler)

extern struct cmd __start___cmd;
extern struct cmd __stop___cmd;
```

I tried some searching on Google but can only understand that "__start___cmd" and "__stop___cmd" are generated by linker. Is there any more layman's explanation to this?

The __COMMAND defined was not used in the codes and I have no idea what is the purpose served. I can only assume that it is related to the extern struct defined.

I downloaded the source code from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/iw/iw-0.9.1.tar.gz

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu(?) Seems kernel related so I would advice asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's interesting in this macro definition is the use of [variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html):

```
#define __COMMAND(sect, name, args, nlcmd, flags, idby, handler)    \
static const struct cmd __cmd_ ## handler ## nlcmd ## idby  \
__attribute__((used)) __attribute__((section("__cmd")))     \
= { sect, name, args, nlcmd, flags, idby, handler }
```

`gcc` (`ld`, rather) generates two magic variables: __start_SECTION and __stop_SECTION. Those can be used to retrieve the start and end addresses of a section.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552710/how-do-you-get-the-start-and-end-addresses-of-a-custom-elf-section-in-c-gcc)